# Casting mislead while in the ethereal plane

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion

If *mislead* is cast while the spellcaster is in the Border Ethereal (from the *etherealness* spell), is the illusory copy created in the ethereal plane?

If yes, then would it remain there also after the caster has interrupted their *etherealness* and so the caster would still be able to perceive using the senses of the illusory ethereal copy and move it as an ethereal traveler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use Project Image and Ethereal to make an illusory, ethereal scout?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115857/can-i-use-project-image-and-ethereal-to-make-an-illusory-ethereal-scout)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73440/discussion-between-rubiksmoose-and-conduit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## This should work

> You step into the border regions of the Ethereal Plane, in the area where it overlaps with your current plane.

So with *etherealness*, you move physically into the Ethereal Plane.

> You become invisible at the same time that an illusory double of you appears where you are standing.

And *mislead* created an illusory double where you are standing.

Thus, your illusory double should indeed be in the Ethereal Plane with you.

When you end *etherealness*, the illusory double would stay in the plane because no effects from either spell say it would or even can come with you.

Once you are no longer ethereal, you should be able to control and use your illusory double in every way described by the spell's description. There are no range or concentration effects or any other kinds of interactions that would forbid this.

Thus, you should get an ethereal scout for one hour.